# How to make first character of word uppercase, if word followed by number, then make the first alphabet in uppercase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

suppose the input string is `1 w 2 r 3g` then the output should be `1 w 2 r 3G`.
here is the code:

```
s='hello kiran 3g'
s=s.title().splitlines()
print(s)
for ele in s:
    if ele[0].isalpha:
        ele[0].upper()
    else:
        ele[1].upper()
s1=' '.join(s)
print(s1)
```

Comment: Could you put the code in a code block? It is easier to read that way

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex with `Lookbehind` --> `(?<=[0-9])` and followed by lower case letter `[a-z]`.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s='hello kiran 3g'
print(re.sub(r"(?<=[0-9])([a-z])", lambda x: x.group(1).upper(), s))
# --> hello kiran 3G

print(re.sub(r"(?<=[0-9])([a-z])", lambda x: x.group(1).upper(), '1 w 2 r 3g'))
# --> 1 w 2 r 3G
```

Comment: Some explanations would be better - this kind of "code only" answers tend to encourage "copy-paste programming", which we all know is a disaster.

Comment: @Rakesh suppose `s='hel34lo kiran 3guru'` then the output according to your code is `hel34Lo kiran 3Guru`. But OP wanted to the output to be `hel34lo kiran 3Guru`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
import re
s='hello kiran 3guru'
ss=s.split()


for i,j in enumerate(ss):
    if not j.isalpha():
        x=re.findall(r'\d+',j)
        if j.startswith(str(x[0])):
            ss[i]=j[:len(x[0])]+j[len(x[0]):].title()

print(' '.join(ss))

s1='hello34 kiran 3guru'
ss=s1.split()

for i,j in enumerate(ss):
    if not j.isalpha():
        x=re.findall(r'\d+',j)
        if j.startswith(str(x[0])):
            ss[i]=j[:len(x[0])]+j[len(x[0]):].title()

print(' '.join(ss))

s2='hello24 kir24an 34guru45'
ss=s2.split()
for i,j in enumerate(ss):
    if not j.isalpha():
        x=re.findall(r'\d+',j)
        if j.startswith(str(x[0])):
            ss[i]=j[:len(x[0])]+j[len(x[0]):].title()


print(' '.join(ss))
```

---

```
hello kiran 3Guru
hello24 kiran 3Guru
hello24 kir24an 34Guru45
```

`isalpha()` will return `True` if the whole string contains alphabets only else `False`. `s.split(' ')` will return a list `['hello', 'kiran', '3g']`. Then convert `'3g'` using `upper()` and join them using `join()`.

Comment: I wanted to make only first alphabet capital, even if the word contains 1st character as numeric, then, in that case, it should make only 1st character capital Not all characters capital. https://stackoverflow.com/users/12416453/ch3ster

Comment: @surenderpal I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: @surenderpal I have used `re.findall`

Comment: @surenderpal Please accept the answer if it helped you by clicking the tick mark beside my answer if helps the community at large in identifying the correct answer. Happy new year.